# How can I make the color of the text in my php code red?

Tags: php

I wanted to make the word "Unable" in red and "Used" in green
Thanks for your help

```
$paragrap .= $used->NAME." - ".(empty($used->is_complete) ? 'Unable' : 'Used')." - ".$helper->timeLeft($used->created)."<br>";
```

Comment: Assuming that this is something that will go on a web page. Do you know HTML and CSS? If so, the answer should be fairly obvious. If not, I'm afraid there's a lot of reading you need to do, or you'll be asking questions like this here every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using html and css. Here is an example using inline css.

`$paragrap .= $used->NAME." - ".(empty($used->is_complete) ? '<span style="color: red;">Unable</span>' : '<span style="color: green;">Used</span>')." - ".$helper->timeLeft($used->created)."<br>";`

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced my code with the one your provided but it did not work for me